# Parse csv data to create folders and record folder name

Tags: powershell, csv

Hi I am trying to make a script that parses a csv and 
Creates a folder for each line then Copies the item from a path specified in the csv to a location.  Currently I get an error saying Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. Could someone please help

```
CSV Structure
FileLocation
K:\Folder\File
```

Powershell Content

```
$csv = Import-Csv c:\export.csv


Foreach ($line in $csv){
    $inc = $i++
    mkdir $inc
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FileLocation -destination c:\users\bford.$inc -Recurse
    }
```

Comment: `$_.FileLocation` -> `$line.FileLocation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question:

The **`foreach` *iteration variable* is `$line`**, yet an attempt is made to use `$_` instead, which is *undefined* (`$null`) inside the loop body.

Therefore, replacing `$_` with `$line` fixes the problem:

```
$csv = Import-Csv c:\export.csv

Foreach ($line in $csv){
    $inc = $i++
    mkdir $inc
    # $line is the iteration variable, not $_
    Copy-Item -Path $line.FileLocation -destination c:\users\bford.$inc -Recurse
}
```

**Automatic variable `$_` (a.k.a. `$PSItem`) is defined by PowerShell only in specific contexts, such as in *pipelines***, usable in the script blocks passed to the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*.

Despite the unfortunately named `foreach` *alias* of the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*, it is distinct from the `foreach` statement: the former can - *only* - use `$_` (`$PSItem`), whereas the latter *must* use whatever iteration variable is chosen (e.g., in the case above, `$line`).

**Choosing between the `foreach` statement and the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet comes down to performance vs. memory use:**

- Use the pipeline and the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet* to process one object at a time, *keeping memory use constant, at the expense of performance.*
- Use the `foreach` *statement* to process a (typically) already-loaded-into-memory-as-a-whole collection *quickly, at the expense of memory consumption*.

The slower, but more memory-efficient and more concise equivalent of your solution is therefore:

```
Import-Csv c:\export.csv | ForEach-Object {
  mkdir ($inc = $i++); Copy-Item -Path $_.FileLocation -destination c:\users\bford.$inc -Recurse
}
```

Note that `$i` is implicitly initialized to `0` when `++` is applied to it, but it's better to explicitly initialize it first, which you could do in a separate statement *beforehand*, or in a a `-Begin` block passed to `ForEach-Object`, for instance.

---

#### Optional reading: Unifying `foreach` and `ForEach-Object` with respect to `$_`

While it's important to understand the different use cases for the `foreach` *statement* vs. the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*, there is value in standardizing the use of `$_`:

This [issue I've created on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3830) argues that the following *should* be possible - but currently (pre-v6) isn't:

```
# WISHFUL THINKING: without an explicit iteration variable, define $_
# implicitly, as with the ForEach-Object *cmdlet*.
foreach ($csv) {
  mkdir ($inc = $i++)
  Copy-Item -Path $_.FileLocation -destination c:\users\bford.$inc -Recurse
}
```